# Problems with Symfony 5.1's prod cache and disabling it

Tags: symfony, symfony5

The problem I've been having is that whatever changes I made to twig templates, they *never* appear on the PROD site without cache:clear commands in console.

There are times when checking rapid iterations on a live site are useful without a lot of shell cache clearing.

This led me to ask, Is there a simple way to temporarily disable Symfony 5.1's PROD caches (so that it works more like DEV caches) on a fairly standard setup?

There are a number of documents such as https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/twig.html -- but they didn't really help resolve the issues I've had.

Comment: What version of Symfony are you using?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why not to enable the DEV mode?

Comment: @FlorianMoser Just because I don't particularly want to go into DEV on a live site just to see html updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further digging and experimentation, I found that changing:

```
//twig.yaml
twig:
     default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/templates'
     cache: 'false'
     auto_reload: 'true'
```

seemed to do the trick, *but* you still have to **cache:clear** one further time for it to start working.

I have no idea why this should be necessary, but at least it is functioning as expected now.

Comment: The configuration is cached, too ;) So only after running `cache:clear` the new configuration is visible to twig.